# Are there any way to create a whitelist of URLs for a domain in Firefox?

Tags: firefox

Let's say I've got a domain `example.com`. I want to be able to go to `example.com/a` and `example.com/b`, but not to any other URL on this domain (like `example.com/z`). By "go" I mean any type of request, including requests from other pages. Are there any extension or config I can use?

Comment: Nope. You can't do this from client-side. You have to configure the web server to restrict visitors from accessing certain pages in the website by using .htaacess files or PHP session ID's. But there is a lot of options that you can use to block all connections from a website (Such as creating outbound firewall rules, Proxy server misconfiguration, mapping incorrect domain name with IP address or using 3rd party web browser extensions or applications). Also there are a lot of apps and parental controls which do content filtering (even at a strict level), they can't help you in this regard.

Comment: @WasifHasan,  no, I'm not an owner of the site, it is not what I'm looking to. I'm basically looking for an adblock which uses whitelist instead of blacklist, because the website loads ads from `domain.com/randomletters/randomletters`, and it can't really be fixed with normal adblocking solutions.

Comment: Not possible unless you are the administrator of the web server.

Comment: @WasifHasan but why? I mean, if adblockers can find if my URL matches a list of sites, why can't there be a solution which checks if URL doesn't match such a list? What I want is to just block some requests from my local browser, not from all the clients of this server

Comment: I think that one thing you are overlooking here is the potential ease of breaking the pages being viewed. Web pages rarely load resources from a single source. That means that for most web pages, you would need to whitelist multiple URLs. Assuming a web page used nothing but static images loaded from a single source, you would need to have a minimum of two URLs whitelisted to merely view the page without it breaking.